# Objects prints as a String

Tags: javascript, json

this my JS code

```
<script>
            let students ="[
{
            "name": "Shaif",
            "age": "33",
            "height": "170"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shahin",
            "age": "34",
            "height": "176"
        }
]"
    console.log(JSON.parse(students)[0].age);
```

My JSON is

```
[
{
            "name": "Shaif",
            "age": "33",
            "height": "170"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shahin",
            "age": "34",
            "height": "176"
        }
]
```

now i'm getting error
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**
I need know why this error

Comment: You have unescaped characters in your string. You must be escape all " to \" in your string.

Comment: Uh, don't put JSON strings in your source code. Just make it an object literal: `let students = [{"name": "Shaif", …}, …]; console.log(students[0].age);`. No `JSON.parse` necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a better idea to create an object rather than making your JSON as a string.

You can update your code to as follows:

```js
let students = [
        {
            "name": "Shaif",
            "age": "33",
            "height": "170"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shahin",
            "age": "34",
            "height": "176"
        }
];
console.log(students[0].name);
```

In order to get your JSON object from an external local file, you've to create your JSON file as follows:-

```
student = '[
        {
            "name": "Shaif",
            "age": "33",
            "height": "170"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shahin",
            "age": "34",
            "height": "176"
        }
]';
```

Then, you've to mention the path of the JSON file in the script tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="student.json"></script>
```

And then get the JSON object from the JSON file using `JSON.parse()` as follows:

```
var students = JSON.parse(student);
console.log(students[0].name);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use json from a file students .json, that's why i use json.parse. but its not working

Comment: @ShaifShahin But you don't need it here because here you're already creating an object for JSON. Though it's a different thing if you want to get the JSON object from a different file instead of manually writing the JSON objects here.

Comment: How to get objects from different file using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid defining JavaScript items this way. Try defining them like this.

```js
let students = [
{
            "name": "Shaif",
            "age": "33",
            "height": "170"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shahin",
            "age": "34",
            "height": "176"
        }
]
console.log(students[0].age);
```

Alternatively, if you can't. Try storing them elsewhere and importing them either with fetch or some other method.

Comment: The linebreaks would need escaping as well. But this is still a bad idea.

Comment: @Bergi agreed. I've changed my answer to use a non-string approach, but provided an alternative for storing JSON in strings.